ESP32 GPIO pin only activates inside a while loop in MicroPython
I am using an ESP32 with MicroPython to control a motor driver. I have created a class for the motor that allows me to set the motor's power using a setPower method. However, I have encountered an issue where the GPIO pin used to control the motor only activates (sets to "high") if I call setPower(1) inside a while loop. If I try to activate the motor before the loop, the pin does not remain active.
I even added timeouts hoping it was just a boot issue, but that didn't work.
from lib.Driver import *
from time import sleep_ms as delay

delay(3000)  # Wait 3 seconds to let the ESP32 boot

p = Motor(PORT_1A)   # Create Motor instances
p2 = Motor(PORT_2A)

driver = TB6612FNG(p, p2, STBY_A)

print("Pin activated")
driver.motorB.setPower(1)  # Attempt to set power to 1 before the loop

while True:
    delay(1000)  # Wait 1 second
    print("Running...")

Observed Behavior:

The motor does not activate when driver.motorB.setPower(1) is called outside the while loop.
If I move driver.motorB.setPower(1) inside the while loop, the motor activates and runs as expected.
If I remove the while loop completely, the motor activates as well.
Here is the version that works correctly:

I thought it was perhaps a problem caused because the Esp32 did not maintain the high state of the pin, but even when I put a 10 second sleep in the loop, the pin does not return to a low state.
This is the code that "works":

from lib.Driver import *
from time import sleep_ms as delay


p = Motor(PORT_1A)
p2 = Motor(PORT_2A)


driver = TB6612FNG(p, p2, STBY_A);

while True:
    
    driver.motorB.setPower(1)
    

I also thought it was because of my esp's firmware, but I tried with the last two versions:
v1.24.1 (2024-11-29) .bin / [.app-bin] / [.elf] / [.map] / [Release notes] (latest)
v1.24.0 (2024-10-25) .bin / [.app-bin] / [.elf] / [.map] / [Release notes]
and the same thing happens with both.
This is the code I use to control the TB6612FNG H-bridge:
from machine import Pin, PWM
import time

PORT_1A = [26,25,27]
PORT_2A = [32,4,0]
STBY_A = 33

PORT_1B = [15,16,2]
PORT_2B = [18,19,23]
STBY_B = 17



class Motor:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        
        if len(args)==1 and isinstance(args[0], list):
            p = args[0]
            
            in1 = p[0]
            in2 = p[1]
            pwm_pin = p[2]
        elif len(args)==3:
            in1 = args[0]
            in2 = args[1]
            pwm_pin = args[2]
        else:
            raise ValueError("se requieren 3 argumentos o una lista")
        """
        Clase para controlar un motor individual.
        :param in1: Pin para la dirección IN1.
        :param in2: Pin para la dirección IN2.
        :param pwm_pin: Pin PWM para la velocidad.
        """
        self.in1 = Pin(in1, Pin.OUT)
        self.in2 = Pin(in2, Pin.OUT)
        self.pwm = PWM(Pin(pwm_pin), freq=1000)  # PWM a 1 kHz
        self.direction = 1  # Dirección predeterminada
        self.stop()  # Por seguridad, inicializa el motor detenido

    def set_direction(self, direction):
        """
        Configura la dirección del motor.
        :param direction: 'forward' para dirección normal o 'reverse' para invertir el giro.
        """
        if direction in ['forward', 'reverse']:
            self.direction = 1 if direction == "forward" else -1
        else:
            raise ValueError("La dirección debe ser 'forward' o 'reverse'.")

    def setPower(self, power):
        """Controla la velocidad y dirección del motor.
        Parámetro power: -1 (máxima velocidad atrás) a 1 (máxima velocidad adelante).
        """
        power = max(min(1, power), -1)

        self.duty_cycle = abs(int(power * 1023))  # Convierte el valor en 0-1023 (PWM)

        if power == 0:
            # Detener el motor
            self.in1.value(0)
            self.in2.value(0)
            self.pwm.duty(0)
        elif power * self.direction > 0:
            # Adelante
            self.in1.value(1)
            self.in2.value(0)
            self.pwm.duty(self.duty_cycle)
        else:
            # Atrás
            self.in1.value(0)
            self.in2.value(1)
            self.pwm.duty(self.duty_cycle)

    def stop(self):
        """
        Detiene el motor.
        """
        self.in1.off()
        self.in2.off()
        self.pwm.duty(0)


class TB6612FNG:
#     def __init__(self, ain1, ain2, pwma, bin1, bin2, pwmb, stby):
#         """
#         Clase para controlar el controlador TB6612FNG con dos motores.
#         :param ain1, ain2, pwma: Pines del Motor A.
#         :param bin1, bin2, pwmb: Pines del Motor B.
#         :param stby: Pin de Standby (habilitación).
#         """
#         self.stby = Pin(stby, Pin.OUT)
#         self.stby.on()  # Activa el controlador (quita Standby)
# 
#         # Inicialización de los dos motores usando la clase Motor
#         self.motorA = Motor(ain1, ain2, pwma)
#         self.motorB = Motor(bin1, bin2, pwmb)
    def __init__(self, *args):
        
        if len(args)==1 and isinstance(args[0], list):
            p = args[0]
            if len(args[0])==7:    
                ain1 = p[0]
                ain2 = p[1]
                pwma = p[2]
                bin1 = p[3]
                bin2 = p[4]
                pwmb = p[5]
                
                stby = p[6]
            else:
                raise ValueError("se requieren 7 argumentos correspondientes a los 7 pines")
        elif len(args)==7:
            ain1 = args[0]
            ain2 = args[1]
            pwma = args[2]
            bin1 = args[3]
            bin2 = args[4]
            pwmb = args[5]
            
            stby = args[6]
        elif len(args)==3:
            self.motorA = args[0]
            self.motorB = args[1]
            self.stby = Pin(args[2], Pin.OUT)
            self.stby.on()
        else:
            raise ValueError("se requieren los 7 pines del driver o 1 lista que los contenga a todos")
            
        """
        Clase para controlar el controlador TB6612FNG con dos motores.
        :param ain1, ain2, pwma: Pines del Motor A.
        :param bin1, bin2, pwmb: Pines del Motor B.
        :param stby: Pin de Standby (habilitación).
        """
        
        if(self.motorA is None):
            self.stby = Pin(stby, Pin.OUT)
            self.stby.on()  # Activa el controlador (quita Standby)

            # Inicialización de los dos motores usando la clase Motor
            self.motorA = Motor(ain1, ain2, pwma)
            self.motorB = Motor(bin1, bin2, pwmb)

    def standby_on(self):
        """Activa el modo Standby."""
        self.stby.off()

    def standby_off(self):
        """Desactiva el modo Standby."""
        self.stby.on()




